# buttons for scrolling left and right in HorizontalScrollView in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a subclass of 'HorizontalScrollView' in which there are variable size images. I want to show two buttons left and right just below HorizontalScrollView. On clicking left button the horizontalscollView should scroll left by size of first non visible image on left side so now this image is visible and same with right button. I also want the respective button to disappear if end of the list is reached on that side.

Can someone help me in doing this

Answer (score 0):

just implement the listeners correctlly like so:
this method gets an array of images id and scrolls to the one supplied in the data
use getLeft and getRight appropriatlly

```
        /**
             * handles button presses that requiere extra data to be passed along 
             * for dynamic created buttons
             * in this app it uses mainly for the navigation bar buttons 
             * @author new
             *
             */
            public class ButtonHandler implements OnClickListener,Runnable 
            {
                private int_data;//current left or right location
                private ArrayList<Integer> _resultId;//the id's of the imagess
                private Activity _activity;

                public ButtonHandler(String data,ArrayList<Integer> resultId,Activity activity)
                {
                    _data=data;
                    _resultId=resultId;
                    _activity=activity;
                }

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                     View currentView=_activity.findViewById(_resultId.get(_data));
                     ScrollView scrollView=(ScrollView) _activity.findViewById(R.id.resultScroll);
                     scrollView.scrollTo(0, currentView.getLeft());
//get new image for nextClick
                     Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
                     scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
                    for (Int i:_resultId)
                    {
                        if (_resultId.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) 
                        {// Any portion of the imageView, even a single pixel, is within the visible window
                            data=i;

                         }
                     }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    new Handler().post(this);

                }

            }
```